# Routing Configuration sending some traffic over VPN

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, openvpn, netstat

I have a `DD-WRT` router with an `OpenVPN` service configured.  I'd like to send only certain source IP's over the vpn connection.

I believe my current routing table (as seen with
`netstat -rn`) sends all my traffic over the vpn on interface `tun1`.  From what I understand the routing table is a "fall through" table so in this case because the 1st entry is `0.0.0.0` all traffic will go through the `tun1` interface.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.182.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun1
0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 br0
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 br0
10.182.1.1      10.182.1.5      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 tun1
10.182.1.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun1
46.23.68.178    10.0.1.1        255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 br0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 lo
128.0.0.0       10.182.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 br0
```

My goal is to only route 1 or 2 websites via the Website - specifically `a1505.g2.akamai.net` which according to `NSLookup` maps to the following IPs

- Address: 195.59.150.43
- Address: 195.59.150.26

I believe what is required is 3 steps.

1) Issue some sort of `iptables` command to delete the 1st routing entry - which in doing so would stop sending traffic through the vpn `tun1`
2) Issue two commands to tell the destination `195.59.150.43` and `195.59.150.26` to route through `tun1`

However i find iptables to be rather confusing in all honesty.

Is this the correct approach and if so could somebody perhaps give me a sample command or two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand the routing table is a "fall through" table

Not really. The routing table is ordered from "most specific route" to "least specific route". Your default route is via `br0`, and is defined as the route of last resort because there is no netmask (i.e. `genmask` is `0.0.0.0`).

> because the 1st entry is 0.0.0.0 all traffic will go through the tun1 interface

Although this is the correct conclusion, unfortunately it's the wrong reasoning. Here is your routing table ordered visually to represent the order used for routing (top is best match):

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
10.182.1.1      10.182.1.5      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 tun1
10.182.1.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun1
46.23.68.178    10.0.1.1        255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 br0

10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 br0

169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 br0

127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 lo

0.0.0.0         10.182.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun1
128.0.0.0       10.182.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun1

0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 br0
```

The default route is still via `br0`. However, there are two more specific routes (the netmask is `128.0.0.0`) each of which will match half the numerically available IPv4 address space, so these will match all non-local traffic.

---

> My goal is to only route 1 or 2 websites via the Website - specifically a1505.g2.akamai.net which according to `nslookup` maps to the following IPs: `195.59.150.43` and `195.59.150.26`.

I'm not sure what you mean by "the Website"; I'm going to assume that's `tun1` and that you want to stop all your traffic going that way.

To do this with OpenVPN you simply remove the directive `route-gateway def1` from its configuration file. (If you're using something like NetworkManager then there should be an option you need to untick that marks the connection as your default route.)

Having done this all you need to do is to add two routes, one for each host, via the gateway for `tun1`:

```
route add -host 195.59.150.43 gw 10.182.1.5
route add -host 195.59.150.26 gw 10.182.1.5
```

These are host routes so the netmask is implicitly `/32` (i.e `255.255.255.255`), so they take precedence over everything and in my visually ordered table would be with the three entries at the top of the list.

Actually, you should be able to do this in the OpenVPN configuration file, too. This would allow the routes to be brought up and removed automatically with the VPN itself. Depending on your setup the configuration would either be in the server, where the routes would get "pushed" to the client, or as directives in the client's OpenVPN configuration file:

```
route 195.59.150.43
route 195.59.150.26
```

Comment: By "website" I mean the two host IP's.  You got my jist in any case.

Comment: Could you update the answer to also show how to remove a route? - I'm not sure I'm able to disable the VPN default routes

Comment: @Jeef, `route delete 0.0.0.0/1 gw 10.182.1.5` and `route delete 128.0.0.0/1 gw 10.182.1.5`. Fixing the configuration would be preferable, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `route` command instead of `iptables`:

```
route 111.112.113.114 gw 10.182.1.5
```

Or you can also push the route from `openvpn` server's side.